# What does "ever having happened" mean?

Tags: meaning, differences

I was listening to a Doctor Who podcast episode, and got confused by this line:

> She (The Doctor)’s supposed to be here. She’s supposed to fix things like this. Or stop them from ever happening. Or ever having happened. "

What are the differences between "ever happening" and "ever having happened"?

Comment: They are time travellers. They can prevent things from happening in the future ("ever happening"), or in the past ("ever having happened").

Comment: Oh got it (light bulb moment)! Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: *Someone reached their 21st birthday without ever **having** sex. Someone else reached their 21st birthday without ever **having had** sex.* There's no need to invoke time travellers   to explain what if any difference Past Perfect Continuous makes in such contexts. My two examples are effectively "synonymous" - it's just that the first draws more attention to what was [not] being done ***before age 21***, where the second emphasises the *state* of the subject ***at age 21***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I am concerned about the parallel between your example and the OP's. As "Dr Who" salient attribute is time travel, it must be invoked in order to provide the context in which it will be understood. In *Someone reached their 21st birthday without ever having sex. / Someone else reached their 21st birthday without ever having had sex.* there is a direct time reference: *21st birthday*. In the OP's example, other than the auxiliary, there is not. It is the verb that is doing the work.

Comment: @Greybeard: I'm not entirely convinced *reaching one's 21st birthday* is significantly different simply because it references a ***specific*** time. My example could just as well have been *Someone **matured / aged / grew old** without having [had] sex*. That refers to a ***process*** rather than to any particular time or event, whereas almost by definition, OP's *something **happening*** refers to an event located in time (unless it didn't *actually* happen because Dr Who altered the course of history, for example! :)

Answer (score 2):

Just to repeat the comment made by Weather Vane into an answer

The doctor is a time traveller, so tenses get very tense (sorry bad joke)
It is saying the doctor usually fixes thing "after they have happened"

or fix the event before it even becomes a problem "ever having happened"

Imagine a time traveller going back in time and convincing Adolf Hitler's parents that having children was a very bad idea. The time traveller would have fixed the second world war by it "never having happened"*.

*Please don't tell me all the ways this isn't true this isn't the history board.

Comment: Best to convert others' answers-in-comments to Community wikis if they're correct (they perhaps didn't _answer_ because they felt the question was subtly off-topic. I'd agree here; the question involves comprehension (of the situation) rather than how English works.

Comment: This is a succinct answer to the question, not a mere parroting of comments. It doesn't need to be converted to a community wiki.

Answer (score 0):

You can read the sentence

> She’s supposed to fix things from ever having happened.

as meaning

> She should have prevented things from ever happening (*but they **have happened already** and it **is too late now***.)

Comment: (1) I think in the first quote "fix" should be "stop"; (2) it is _not_ too late now if you happen to be in possession of a time-travelling police box...